# Laravel 9 Faker: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, faker

I have a faker like this:

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'que_title' => $this->faker->sentence(),
            'que_body' => $this->faker->text(),
        ];
    }
```

But when I run this I get this error:

**SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'que_title' at row 1**

And for `que_title` column, I have set this in Migration:

```
$table->string('que_title',70);
```

So how can I solve this issue and determine the size of generated `sentence()` in faker ?

Comment: you should trim the length of the ``que_title / $this->faker->sentence()`` to 70 or remove the limit of 70 characters.

Comment: @OMiShah So you mean there is no way for determining the size of `$this->faker->sentence()` ?

Comment: you could do soemthing like this ``substr($this->faker->sentence(), 70)`` or you could use the ``text`` method instead of the ``sentence`` which accepts length. ``$this->faker->text(70);``